# Django best way to stream video to your frontend (php or react.js)

Tags: django, video-streaming

I want to make a website for watching videos like vimeo or youtube but i have no idea how to watch/stream the videos on the frontend from my django backend.
So i have the videos in my database how will someone watch them from his browser

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve that is put your videos on separate server (special for videos) and store links for those videos in your django application

after that you can send video link to your frontend and manage it